# Compare dicts and record changes

Tags: python, performance, hash-map

My goal is to continually update an object and record any changes and the times they were made at. The input has to be JSON but the output/storage format doesn't.

This function will check a JSON object/dictionary against a reference object and return a list containing the updated object and another object containing just the updates.

I've tested it a bit and I think it handles inconsistencies in the objects, such as the old object not having the correct nesting.

It only compares new to old, so any missing keys in the new version won't be removed from the old version. It's not memory-impervious but there's no recursion so depth itself isn't a problem.

How can I make my approach more efficient? (Faster, less steps involved)

```
def getFromDict(dataDict, mapList):
    return reduce(lambda d, k: d[k], mapList, dataDict)

def setInDict(dataDict, mapList, value):
    getFromDict(dataDict, mapList[:-1])[mapList[-1]] = value

def record_changes(obj, keys, key, value):
    for _ in xrange(len(keys)+10):
        try:
            setInDict(obj, keys+[key], value)
            return obj
        except:
            for i in range(len(keys)+1)[1:]:
                try:
                    assert isinstance(getFromDict(obj, keys[:i]), dict)
                except:
                    setInDict(obj, keys[:i], {})
    else:
        raise Exception

def compare_object(N, record):
    """
    :param:N new object
    :param:record old object
    """
    changes = {}
    D = N.copy()
    nested_keys = []
    for key in D:
        if isinstance(D[key], dict):
            nested_keys.append([key])
        else:
            if D[key] != record.get(key, None):
                record[key] = D[key]
                changes[key] = D[key]
    for keys in nested_keys:
        d = getFromDict(N, keys)
        for key in d:
            if isinstance(d[key], dict):
                nested_keys.append(keys+[key])
            else:
                try:
                    if d[key] != getFromDict(record, keys+[key]):
                        setInDict(record, keys+[key], d[key])
                        changes = record_changes(changes, keys, key, d[key])
                except:
                    # record = Help(D, record, keys+[key])
                    record = record_changes(record, keys, key, d[key])
                    changes = record_changes(changes, keys, key, d[key])
    return [record, changes]
```

Usage:

```
>>> new = {'a':{'b':1, 'q':0}, 'c':5}
>>> old = {'a':{'b':2, 'q':0}, 'f':9}
>>> print compare_object(new, old)
[{'a': {'q': 0, 'b': 1}, 'c': 5, 'f': 9}, {'a': {'b': 1}, 'c': 5}]
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want a variation of `dict.update` that recursively update inner dicts; and you want it to record changes as you go.

I’m afraid that your solution is way too complicated for that:

- `compare_object` has two for loops (`for key in D` and `for key in d`) that mainly perform the same kind of task. The former being an initialization to the outer loop of the latter.
- `compare_object` copies its `N` parameter which is never modified and modify `record` in place (thus there is no need in returning it); which is at best misleading, at worse a bug.
- `record_change` seems to be only an extremely verbose and convoluted way of calling `setInDict` while ensuring that each level of nesting will actually contain a dictionary.

As for the actual coding style:

- Always specify the kind of exception you’re expecting in an `except` clause; as in you probably don't expect to catch `IndexError` when calling `record_changes`.
- Raising `Exception` is also worth noting. You should either declare your own exception or raise a more specific one.
- Iterating over keys in a dictionary and repeatedly calling `d[key]` reads poorly: it's better to iterate over the pairs of keys and values returned by `items` or `iteritems` (Python 2): `for key, value in d.iteritems():`.
- [As already stated around here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/118070/84718) `AssertionError`s are not meant to control the flow of execution. If I run your code in optimized mode (`-O` switch on the command line), your code breaks.

Now before getting back to the algorithm, let me introduce you to [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault): it works pretty much the same than `dict.get` but instead of just returning the default value in case the key does not exist, it set the key to that default value if it doesn't exist before returning the value.

With that information in mind, let's take an empty file and build a function that update a dictionary and recursively update inner dictionaries.

1. The name should convey (at least part of) this:

   ```
   def update_inner(orig, update):
   ```
2. The function should return values that actually changed:

   ```
       change = {}
       ...
       return change
   ```
3. The function should update values of the original dict with values from the `update` dict (and still record changes):

   ```
       change = {}
       for key, value in update.iteritems():
           if value != orig.get(key):
               orig[key] = change[key] = value
       return change
   ```
4. The function should recurse to update inner dictionaries:

   ```
   def update_inner(orig, update):
       change = {}
       for key, value in update.iteritems():
           try:
               # Consider value is a dict, so recurse
               changed = update_inner(orig, value)
           except AttributeError:
               # We were wrong, value is not a dict, backup to simple update
               if orig.get(key) != value:
                   orig[key] = change[key] = value
           else:
               # We were right, record the changes
               change[key] = changed
       return change
   ```

   Wait no, there is something wrong… We are not keeping track of the keys used to go deeper into `orig` when doing the recursion… Find out why I talked about `setdefault` now?

## Proposed improvements

```
def update_inner(orig, update):
    change = {}
    for key, value in update.iteritems():
        try:
            # Consider value is a dict, so recurse
            changed = update_inner(orig.setdefault(key, {}), value)
        except AttributeError:
            # We were wrong, value is not a dict, backup to simple update
            if orig[key] != value: # Direct access is OK thanks to setdefault above
                orig[key] = change[key] = value
        else:
            # We were right, record the changes
            change[key] = changed
    return change
```

You use it like so:

```
>>> record = {'a':{'b':2, 'q':0}, 'f':9}
>>> new = {'a':{'b':1, 'q':0}, 'c':5}
>>> update_inner(record, new)
{'a': {'b': 1}, 'c': 5}
>>> record
{'f': 9, 'a': {'q': 0, 'b': 1}, 'c': 5}
```

Comment: Won't this reach a recursion limit?

Comment: @user193661 Only if you have around 1000 nested levels. See also https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd highlight is the confusion here. `getFromDict`? `setInDict`? These functions don't come with docstrings, so I don't know what to make of them. I don't know what data to put in. Presumable a dictionary and a list, but of what form? When I tried putting in data I got a key error.

```
getFromDict({43: 231, "banana": 545, "fruity": "licious"}, range(10))

KeyError: 0
```

So it seems that I need to match the range values to keys in my dictionary?

```
>>> d = dict(zip(range(10), range(100, 1000, 100)))
>>> d
{0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 300, 3: 400, 4: 500, 5: 600, 6: 700, 7: 800, 8: 900}
>>> getFromDict(d, range(10))

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

So it seems that they should be lists, ok? So what if I insert an empty list in each spot.

```
>>> d = {x: [] for x in range(10)}
>>> getFromDict(d, range(10))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Right, the lists should contain data.

You see the problem here? I can't test your function, I can't suggest improvements. Before I can do anything I need to know how it works and it's not easy to glean from the short but confusing function you have. I had thought at first glance that each element of the list would be assigned as a key to the dictionary passed in, but now I have no clue what it's for.

You can fix this with a better name. `get` doesn't tell me what I'm getting or what form it is, replace it with a descriptive name that references what the data is, not just the type it's extracted from. Then have a good [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) on what data the function takes and what it returns.

Comment: Usage is like `getFromDict({'a': {'b': {'c': 3}}}, 'abc')` gives you 3.

Comment: @Barry Ah I see now. Even that example in a comment would go a long way towards explaining a complex function.